# How to get /MP option of VC projects using EnvDTE?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, vsix, envdte

I'm developing Visual Studio Add-in to modify VC projects, and I'd like to get/set /MP option (Multi-processor compilation option).
But I can't seem to find the property to change it.
Where is the property for /MP?

Comment: I have searched, but I don't think Microsoft added that property. It should be in VCPlatform or VCCLCompilerTool

Answer (score 1):

I can get the MP option with the code below.

```cs
p.GetEvaluatedPropertyValue("MultiProcessorCompilation");
```

Answer (score -1):

For VC++ projects, you should pass the [/Qpar switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/qpar-auto-parallelizer) to the compiler, via the "Enable Parallel Code Generation" setting in the C/C++|Code Generation property page.

To do this programmatically from a VS package, you can use the [IVCRulePropertyStorage.GetEvaluatedPropertyValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.ivcrulepropertystorage.getevaluatedpropertyvalue?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_VCProjectEngine_IVCRulePropertyStorage_GetEvaluatedPropertyValue_System_String_) method.

For example, given you already have the EnvDTE.Project interface for the project in question:

```
   Project proj = GetSelectedProject();
   VCProject vcProject = (VCProject)proj.Object;
   IVCCollection configs = (IVCCollection)vcProject.Configurations;
   VCConfiguration firstConfig = (VCConfiguration)configs.Item(1);
   IVCCollection rules = firstConfig.Rules;

   IVCRulePropertyStorage p = rules.Item("CL");
   string isParallelCodeGenSet = p.GetEvaluatedPropertyValue("EnableParallelCodeGeneration");
```

Note, the compiler settings are configuration specific, and the code snippet above only uses the first one found. So you'll want to retrieve the property from each Rule associated with the configuration you're interested in.

A few additional links you should review:

[Working with Visual Studio C++ Project Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn655034.aspx)

[How to read/write the new Visual C++ project properties](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/01/14/how-to-readwrite-the-new-visual-c-project-properties/)

[VCConfiguration Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcconfiguration)